# FormFunction custom control's initial value

Tags: input-forms

The second form does not respect `"Input"` value. Both, `"Input"` and using pure functions for `"Control"` are documented.

It does not work in MMA as well as in the cloud. Is this a bug or did I miss something? Is there a workaround?

My original goal was to be able to use it with `Rasterize @ FormFunction[...` as I need to generate some kind of preview and would like not to redo that.

```
FormFunction[{"x" -> <|"Interpreter" -> {1, 2}, 
    "Control" -> RadioButtonBar, "Input" -> 2|>}, func]

FormFunction[{"x" -> <|"Interpreter" -> {1, 2}, 
    "Control" -> Function[RadioButtonBar[##]], "Input" -> 2|>}, func]

FormFunction[{"x" -> <|"Interpreter" -> "String", 
    "Control" -> Function[InputField[##]], "Input" -> "init"|>}, func]
```

[image]